# Unable to find Entity Properties

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am working with a vendor to setup a custom application in Azure AD for our Office 365 Tenant and I've been asked to provide the following Entity Properties by using Azure AD graph:

```
extension_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_sAMAccountName
extension_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_userPrincipalName
```

Reading through Microsoft's documentation, I learned that Azure AD graph explorer is deprecated, so I've been reading through Microsoft's Graph documentation to retrieve these properties.

When I run a GET command for [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id|UserPrincipalName}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bid%7CUserPrincipalName%7D) I get the following set of data (replaced original values with **user** and **xxxx** characters):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": "user",
    "givenName": null,
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": null,
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": null,
    "userPrincipalName": "user@domain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

I haven´t found any reference on the documentation to these types of Entity Properties, am I just using Microsoft Graph the wrong way or am I missing something obvious in their documentation?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the user's extension details,We need to add `$select` statement with the required extension in the users query.

E.g.:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,extension_a95b06210ee248ed93fecf16c272a0d5_MyNewProperty
```

output:
[image]